# django how to get Response in class based view

Tags: django, cookies, django-class-based-views

now i have a class-based view. and i want to set cookie in this view,but i can get the response,but the response is returned in the get methond .so i can not set the cookie to response.so how to get Response in class based view

```
 class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UBaseTemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #in here set cookie,but can get the response 
        #response.set_cookie("success","success")

        return context
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot set_cookie on a `request`, only on `response`, but burhan-khalid was going in the correct direction. `get_context_data` only returns a dictionary, so you cannot access the response there. You have to access it either in `dispatch`, or with a `TemplateView`, in `render_to_response`. Here is an example:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super(MyView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
        response.set_cookie("success","success")
        return response
```

I would suggest you shouldn't do all your processing code in `get_context_data`. You may need to refactor to get the cookie you want set in `render_to_response`.

Comment: this works fine. my question is  i want to  set a flag in cooke in post_context_data to flag the operate is success or fail and then in the get_context_data to get the flag from cookie and show the message in template

Comment: you can see my code in github https://github.com/djangochina/UUBlog. and this is my all class-based view struct.https://github.com/djangochina/UUBlog/blob/master/build/20130918/doc/the%20main%20class%20based%20view.jpg

Comment: can you give me some suggest?

Comment: this UUBlog  all use class-based view

Comment: Where do you want to set the flag? You can set it anywhere like this: `self.success = 'success'` then in `get_context_data` you can add it to the context for the template like this: `context['success'] = self.success` then in `render_to_response`, when you set the cookie, just do `response.set_cookie("success",self.success)`

Comment: set cookie in the post process. and get cookie in get process

Comment: you can see this code .https://github.com/djangochina/UUBlog/blob/master/UUBlog/admin/views/admincategory.py. i have implement a PostContext which is process post data,and a GetContext which is process get data. i need to set a flag in PostCotext and get the flag from cookie in GetContext