# how to set cookie in class based generic view

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views

newbies to django1.6

i want to set cookie in class based generic view  (Listview)

**models.py**

```
class Designation(Models.model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class DesignationList(ListVew):

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ 
        will get 'sort_by' parameter from request,
        based on that objects list is return to template
        """

        col_nm = self.request.GET.get('sort_by', None)


        if col_nm:
            if cookie['sort_on'] == col_nm:
                objects=Designation.objects.all().order_by(col_nm).reverse()
            else:
                cookie['sort_on'] = col_nm
                objects=Designation.objects.all().order_by(col_nm)  
        else:
            objects = Designation.objects.all().order_by('title')
            //set cookie['sort_on']='title'


    return objects
```

**template**
in template im iterating over objects

so initially objects display in sort_by 'title' desc.
"this values is i want to set in cookie".

in template, if user click over title,it will check in cookie 
cookie['sort_on']='title'
then all objects are in asce order

if user click over description,then cookie value is replaced 
cookie['sort_on']='description' and objects are in desc order..

soo,how to set cookie which i can use in whole ListView class.. ?

Thnx in advance..

Comment: I this this previous question should give you the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875803/django-how-to-get-response-in-class-based-view

Answer (score 10):

In order to set/delete cookies you have to have access to the "response" object. To do so, in a class-based view, you can override "render_to_response".

Example:

```
class DesignationList(ListVew):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super(LoginView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
        response.set_cookie('sort_on', 'title')
        return response
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a very good reason, you shouldn't be using cookies, but the [session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/). You can access that inside your methods with `self.request.session`, and it acts like a dictionary.

```
    if col_nm:
        if self.request.session.get('sort_on') == col_nm:
            objects=Designation.objects.all().order_by(col_nm).reverse()
        else:
            self.request.session['sort_on'] = col_nm
            objects=Designation.objects.all().order_by(col_nm)
```

etc.

Comment: I think the question was "How to set cookie" not "How to access". By request.session you can not set.

Comment: @sajid You can set keys in `request.session`. It is a dict-like object. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question asked